# Chromium Renderer process just crashed on Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, cypress, chromium

Running into this issue on Jenkins. I've been running Cypress for a month already and didn't have a problem. Once I updated the version from `5.3.0` -> `5.5.0` started having this issue.

NOTE: My tests are not in a docker container.

```
We detected that the Chromium Renderer process just crashed.

This is the equivalent to seeing the 'sad face' when Chrome dies.

This can happen for a number of different reasons:

- You wrote an endless loop and you must fix your own code
- There is a memory leak in Cypress (unlikely but possible)
- You are running Docker (there is an easy fix for this: see link below)
- You are running lots of tests on a memory intense application
- You are running in a memory starved VM environment
- There are problems with your GPU / GPU drivers
- There are browser bugs in Chromium

You can learn more including how to fix Docker here:

https://on.cypress.io/renderer-process-crashed
```

```
┌────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┐
  │ Cypress:      5.5.0                                                                            │
  │ Browser:      Electron 85 (headless)                                                           │
  │ Specs:        2 found (webapp/authenctication.js, webapp/booking.js)                           │
  │ Searched:     cypress/specs/webapp/authenctication.js, cypress/specs/webapp/booking.js         │
  │ Experiments:  experimentalFetchPolyfill=true,experimentalNetworkStubbing=true                  │
  └────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘
```

Comment: I have the same issue with `Cypress 6.5.0` combined with `Cucumber.js`

Answer (score 1):

After almost two years I got the same problem again. Coincidence? I Think Not!
Cypress runner started crashing for no reason (didn't discover any cause yet) and I had to look for an answer again.

At this time, I've decided to find another approach how to address this issue.  I found these very useful Github issues that helped me to address my issue:

1. [The Chromium Renderer process just crashed - 'sad face' Error #7204](https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress/issues/7204)
2. [If "We detected that the Chromium Renderer process just crashed." still output report #3602](https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress/issues/3602)
3. ["Out of memory. size=47701480 - We detected that the Chromium Renderer process just crashed." when running through Github Action, but works fine when running the process locally. #8879](https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress/issues/8879)

**Final Solution:**
I started from the simplest suggestion and tried to run tests on the headless chrome browser instead of the headless electron. Voilà, It worked!
In order to do that, you just need to pass a couple of additional flags to the run command: `--headless --browser chrome`

Answer (score 0):

same problem in self-hosted GitLab. This is probably because of lack of memory.

the following solutions may help:

1. set `--disable-dev-shm-usage` options: https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress/issues/350#issuecomment-633700002
2. allocate more memory for your Jenkins

Answer (score 0):

This issue was resolved by running Cypress tests inside a Docker container.